# Maven could not resolve dependency of WebSphere provided dependency

Tags: maven, deployment, websphere

I am trying to import a legacy application on IntelliJ and most of the modules have dependencies to com.ibm.tools.target.was and com.ibm.tools.target.portal artifacts.

I am getting this in the Maven window of IntelliJ:

[image]

This is the error message I am getting on mvn install:

> Failed to execute goal on project xxx-managers: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.xxx.xxx-managers:xxx-managers:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.ibm.tools.target:was:pom:8.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I tried to imitate a similar procedure found in the IBM web knowledge center (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/install_server_apis.html) but it did not work.

I added the was_public.pom as maven project and imported the project as a dependency to my other module.

I also tried to add WebSphere as a library dependency:

[image]

Nothing worked.

Please help, thanks in advance.
EDIT: This is my settings.xml (I copied it from an other environment in which the application is working) and it includes IBM repositories:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>standard-extra-repos</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I think you need to install dependencies in your local repo, based on the local installation of WAS. Try this link https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/169427/maven-dependencies-for-websphere-8-application-ser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss some artifacts, e.g. `com.ibm.tools.target:was:pom:8.0.0`, and you need to either specify a repository in your settings.xml, where it should come from or install these artifacts into your local repository.

Comment: I included my settings.xml in the original post. It seems like it already has the repositories specified. Nothing has changed, the problem persists. Those artifacts cannot be found in the maven repository.

Comment: Have you checked in the ibm repositories that the artifacts you miss are indeed existing?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The repositories exists but contain only xml and pom file not jars. The thing is that in the other pc that this project runs my m2 repository folders are similar. No jar files in there too. I was wondering if those dependencies should somehow be provided by the application server. In any case the problem still persists.

Comment: Your missing dependendencies are poms, so no jar files required. The question is if the repositories really contain all the poms/jars/whatever that you reference.

Comment: The repositories contain the pom files and they also exist in my .m2. Everything seems to have downloaded to my .m2 properly but the project cannot be built.

Comment: This might be some caching problem. I would try `mvn clean install` on the command line and see what happens.

Comment: In the console the project is built. There is one problem though. I am using an IBM SDK 1.6 and for that reason I had to downgrade to maven 3.0.4. The console runs maven 3.3. When I switch the maven version in IntelliJ and upgrade to JDK 1.8 the project builds but being IBM and having portlets and other stuff that I am not afmiliar with I have to ask if there it is a possibility that the build is not properly created and I might have problems missing IBM related libraries when I try to run the application?